# Взять данные из формы по индексу или по CSS

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, selenium

Пытаюсь взять список точек из карт Яндекс. Маршруты добавить, сформировать и оптимизировать получилось по xpath. Но как мне их забрать на вывод к примеру в консоль? Порядок точек поменялся, и добавились теги с индексами 1, 2 и тд. Я никак не могу понять за что мне можно ухватиться.
Новые маршруты добавляются с названием в коде "route-field-view _index_2", внутри которого есть еще дополнительные классы. Обратил внимание, что рядом с точкой есть изображение с индексом, посмотрел в CSS там есть параметр

`before { content: '2'; }`

Есть ли возможность вытащить содержимое поля content (а именно 2 в данном случае)?

Пытаюсь сделать через:

`res1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".route-waypoint-icon-view._index_2._activated") print(res1.value_of_css_property('content'))`

Пробовал по разному, но выдает либо текст Normal или None, уж лучше бы ошибку выдал ((

Сама задача для меня обстоит так: взять построчно список добавленных точек. Может это вообще можно сделать как-то по другому?

Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо!

П.С., никогда не писал постов на форумах, сильно не бейте за оформление

Comment: Вытащил значение поле content через execute_script. Для меня остается непонятным то, **как теперь вытащить содержимое (адрес точки) из каждой существующей формы?**. Нужное мне значение находится в куче `div` элементов, и зарыто внутри `input class`, который имеет одинаковое название в div-классах адресов (пример: div class "Route1", div class "Route2" и так далее по кол-ву точек)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Вытащил через `//input[@class='имя_класса']`
Если кто-то в этот момент отвечал на вопрос - прошу прощения за потраченное время.
Спасибо!